# Adding one more information in my front page - beamer

Tags: beamer, titles

I am creating a slide template for a presentation in LaTex using Beamer and i want to add some more information "**Supervised by** " between "Directed by " and "the institue" , so i put

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS} % theme
\title[Project's name]{Project 's name }
\author[My name]{\textbf {Directed by: my name}} % auteur
\institute[Rouen University]{\textbf {Rouen University}}
\date{20 july 2012}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo_ur.jpg}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

the result is given by this picture :
[image]

and i want something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a line break in author field and add the second line.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS} % theme
\title[Project's name]{Project 's name }
\author[My name]{\textbf {Directed by: my name\\ \footnotesize Supervised by: first name, second name}} % auteur
\institute[Rouen University]{\textbf {Rouen University}}
\date{20 july 2012}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See the deleted comment-answer below

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible solution (depending on your specific needs you might need to adjust some lengths and fonts); a new command \titlegraphicii was defined for inclusion of the second logo; it's used in the same way as the standard \titlegraphic

[Code given here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116112/146828)

[image]

Comment: Could you add your code?