# Presentation Beamer [title page]

Tags: beamer

I want to make a cover page as the attached figure. The problem is that the `beamer` has, by default, the macros predefined: `\author{} \title{} ', ...` and their location is fixed by default.
Could you help me?

Here is my code:

```
\title[Short Paper Title]  
{presentation}

\subtitle
{About some things}

\author 
 { Author}


\institute 
{
Department of Computer Science\\
University of Somewhere
}

\date
 {\today}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's one possible solution (depending on your specific needs you might need to adjust some lengths and fonts); a new command `\titlegraphicii` was defined for inclusion of the second logo; it's used in the same way as the standard `\titlegraphic`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\titlegraphicii[1]{\def\inserttitlegraphicii{#1}}
\titlegraphicii{}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
   {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\hfill\inserttitlegraphicii\par}
  \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}%\vskip0.5em
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
  %\vfill
}
\makeatother
\author{Presented by Author}
\title{Presentation Title}
\subtitle{Presentation Subtile}
\institute{Department \\ University}
\date{\today}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{logo1}}
\titlegraphicii{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=2cm]{logo2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\small
{\centering\itshape Jury Members\par}
President: president\par\medskip
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{3pt}}p{.32\textwidth}@{}}
Examiners: & examiner 1 \\
& examiner 2 \\
& examiner 3 \\
& examiner 4
\end{tabular}%
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{3pt}}p{.3\textwidth}@{}}
Supervisor 1: & supervisor \\
Supervisor 2: & supervisor
\end{tabular}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The line

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
```

replaces actual figures with black rectangles; delete that line in your actual document.

Comment: thank you for your answer :)
I met some problems:

- To change the size of the supervisors, I add \ small, but it does not work! the size is fixed!

- I move the declaration \ titlegraphic up to see two parallel logos, right and left. and i add     \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo.jpg}
the problem is always the figure in the center.
to add two parallel figure above (right and left ) and to change the size of text what should I do?

Comment: @physics the size used for supervisors is already `\small` (that's why you don't see any change). Use a smaller size. You didn't mention anything about logos in your original question. Where exactly should they be?

Comment: Please Mr Gonzalo Medina  check my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154562/frame-for-a-title-page

Comment: @Educ I'll take a look after lunch. However, I notice that your new image on that other question doesn't show any logos. Do you still need the logos  above the other information?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina   Thanks so much yes i still need the logos  and have good lunch

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina       please check my new question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155272/frame-for-a-title-page-2 not old one