# How can I put the title below the subtitle with the beamer package?

Tags: beamer, formatting, titles

I'm doing a presentation using the `beamer`-package. My first frame looks like this:

```
\title{Cats, dogs and unicorns}
\subtitle{Topic 3}
\maketitle
```

This puts the subtitle **below** the title. However, I want the subtitle to be **on top** of the title. How can I achieve that?

Comment: There's the beamer template `title page`. You can modify it in order to get what you want. One example of a modified template you can find here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116077/presentation-beamer-title-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the default theme, you can just copy the default title page layout from `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty`

```
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{default}[1][]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
```

And modify it, deleting the argument and swapping title and subtitle:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsubtitle\par% \inserttitle -> \insertsubtitle
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
    \else%
    \vskip0.25em%
    {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\inserttitle\par}% \insertsubtitle -> \inserttitle
    \fi%     
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \vskip1em\par
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
    \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
    \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
    \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
  \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
  {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\title{My title}
\subtitle{sub}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Of course, if you want to use another theme, you might need to modify the related title page layout.

**edit:** If you also want to swap the font, you are free to do this, just swap the arguments of `\usebeamerfont` as suggested by OP. I am not sure if this is always desired, that's why I rejected their edit. Here the according picture, if you do change the fonts.

[image: result2]