# How to make a title page with this style

Tags: beamer

In beamer I would like to make title pages for different presentations with this style:

[image]

I looked at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116112/36831 but that seems much more complicated than I was hoping for.

I didn't really know where to start but here is some LaTeX nonetheless.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\newcommand{\Var}[1]{\ensuremath{\textcolor{varcolor}{#1}}}

\definecolor{varcolor}{RGB}{15,122,183}

\title{Calculus recap.}
%\Var{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}
\author{Author Name}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The easy solution is to NOT use \maketitle.

Comment: @JohnKormylo. That's a very good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I've written would certainly profit from a thorough cleaning.

I'll leave the cleaning part to you, as looking up commands and reading documentation is an essential part of learning.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\definecolor{titlecolor}{RGB}{29, 110, 174}

\title{Calculus recap.}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
\centering
\textcolor{titlecolor}{\large\bfseries Advanced Math – CSXXX}\par
\vskip 1cm
\textcolor{titlecolor}{\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}\par
\bigskip
\small\inserttitle\par
\insertsubtitle\par
\bigskip
\textcolor{titlecolor}{\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}\par
\bigskip
\textcolor{titlecolor}{\small \insertauthor}\par
\insertinstitute\par
\insertdate\par
}

\author{Author Name}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]

\maketitle

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: beamer title page]

Comment: Thank you very much.