# How to add course add format extra fields to titlepage in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles, themes

How can it be added a new field to \titlepage in Beamer?

For example I want to add the name of course and the name of the teacher.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE! Here's a related post discussing how to tweak title pages in `beamer` that may be of use to you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116077/158639

Comment: Thanks! Very help full!